# How to specify the order of parameters in @AllArgsConstructor in lombok

Tags: java, lombok

If I have a class like below,

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
class MyClass{
    private String one;
    private Integer three;  
    private Integer two;   
}
```

What will be the order of parameters in the generated constructor ? Is it always like below,

```
public MyClass(String one, Integer three, Integer two) {
    this.one = one;
    this.three = three;
    this.two = two;        
}
```

I noticed it's the order of declaration in the class itself. But need to confirm it. Couldn't find any documentation that verify that fact.

If not can we define the order of params in anyway ?

Comment: But @AllArgsConstructor don't generate the constructor. You can use the annotation without explicit argument constructor declaration in your class. When you need to call the constructor You can use your IDE to see the order of the parameters.

Comment: @DinaBogdan yes we can use IDE, but just wanted a better clarification on that.

Comment: Also, the order of parameters can be important when some of them have the same types like this example.

Comment: Also, order is important if you wish to Override the clone method.

Answer (score 21):

The lombok document on Constructor, it says: (the last sentence of the third paragraph. Or you can find 'sort' with your browser's find feature)

> The order of the parameters match the order in which the fields appear in your class.

Though the sentence is in the paragraph for `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, the same rule looks to apply to `@AllArgsConstructor`, too.

https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor

Comment: `the sentence is in the paragraph for @RequiredArgsConstructor` That's where I found it confusing. Thanks for the clarification though.