# How to ensure that child class will call the correct super constructor in lombok?

Tags: java, lombok

Say that I have the following classes

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class A {

    private String item1;
    private String item2;
    private String item3;
}
```

and

```
@Data
public class B extends A {

    private String item4;

    @Builder(builderMethodName = "bBuilder")
    public B(String item1, String item2, String item3, String item4) {
        super(item1, item2, item3);
        this.item4 = item4;
    }
}
```

how can I (or is there even a way) to guarantee that the child constructor will call the "correct" constructor when I call the super constructor? More specifically, I want to 100% ensure that the three string values I pass in indeed are set to the correct fields in the parent, and not something where, say, item1 in is set to item2.

I know that I could, for example either:

- explicitly create my own all args constructor
- in the child constructor, call all of the setters of the parent

but I am just curious if Lombok is smart enough, somehow, to set the the fields in the child class to the correct ones in the parent class?

**Edit**:

I know that the order of the fields determine the order of the fields of the constructor, but that to me isn't safe enough, since if someone inserts a new field, say in the middle, then it will throw everything off.

However, perhaps the @SuperBuilder might be something that I could use, as some have suggested, if not, then I will just explicit create my own constructor to guarantee the order of fields.

Comment: Don't use Lombok.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are calling the super constructor explicitly. Lombok isn't generating it.

Comment: https://twitter.com/simas_ch/status/1236565854734647299

Comment: Also, not sure why you aren't using SuperBuilder. https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder

Comment: @britho36 1) There is no JPA here. 2) This advocates avoiding 1 specific annotation within the entire library, it does not advocate avoiding the entire library 3) should I know/care who that random Twitter profile belongs to?

Comment: In your class `B` you call the constructor `super(item1, item2, item3);`. That is the AllArgsConstructor. Since it takes all 3 fields as parameter. More at: https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor

Comment: ..so, when you mix them up (item1-3, in B constructor), it's you to blame. But regarding lombok, you can be safe: >"The *order of the parameters* (also in all args constructor) match the *order* in which the *fields appear in your class*." - https://stackoverflow.com/q/49106072/592355

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify the order of parameters in @AllArgsConstructor in lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106072/how-to-specify-the-order-of-parameters-in-allargsconstructor-in-lombok)

Comment: With mutable classes, many-args-constructors are better to be avoided. Consider using fluent setters like `new B().setItem1("a").setItem("2").....` or `new B().item1("a").item("2").....` (configurable via [`@Accessors`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the parameters of an `@AllArgsConstructor` matches the order of the fields in the source code. So right now you are safe.

However, if you later modify the order of the fields in `A` (or rename them), you will get wrong assignments (or wrong parameter names in your builder), but no compiler error.

But there is an easy way out: Use `@SuperBuilder`, and remove `@Data`. (Note that you need `@SuperBuilder` on all classes in your hierarchy.) You won't get `@AllArgsConstructor`s, changes to the field order are irrelevant, and name changes are immediately reflected in the builder classes.

If that is not possible, your only choice is to put a big fat warning comment into `A` advising later coders not to mess around with the names and order.

Comment: Sure, but I wouldn't use builder for mutable classes as about all you get is fluent chained setters. `+++` The big fat warning could be accompanied by a simple unit test.